# 14.04 with pre-installed 12.04 in the same laptop (Live CD) [Installation]

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, system-installation, live-cd

I want to install the 14.04 LTS version on my laptop where I use now 12.04 LTS, I want to use a Live CD and I don't know if it will erase my 12.04 or integrate it on grub in the start on my laptop.

1) Can I get the both on the same laptop using only the Live CD (Choosing in the grub interface)?

2) How can this be done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just start your computer with the 14.04 CD, start the installation and select to have it installed alongside your current installation when that question comes.

Comment: Will this question come ?

Comment: I have a problem when I choose the size of the partition (After clicking on Install button, it's freezing) ...

Comment: @user289206: Don't know why it freezes.. What if you just accept the suggested value? You can always resize it afterwards.